# What R package can I use for counting the occurrence of unique strings in an array

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, word-count

I need to count the occurrence of unique words in a series of words and assign a value of 1 when a new word appears in the series. I wonder what R package or function could do that.

```
    test <- c(cat, dog, table, cat, chair, car, bus, 
    chair, school, car, chair, table)

    #expected result (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

Thanks,
Chamil

Comment: YOu can use `as.integer(duplicated(test))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get a logical vector with `duplicated` and coerce it to binary with `as.integer`.  The `duplicated` returns TRUE for every duplicate elements, by negating (`!`) the TRUE returns FALSE and FALSE as TRUE which is converted to 1 (TRUE)  or 0 (FALSE) with `as.integer`

```
as.integer(!duplicated(test))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
test <- c("cat", "dog", "table", "cat", "chair", "car", "bus",
          "chair", "school", "car", "chair", "table")
```

Comment: Akrun. Thanks very much. This solves the problem. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChamilRathnayake  If the answer solves the problem, please accept it as the answer and upvote. You might also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)